# Redirecting iframes no different url

Tags: iframe, external

Some random has purchased a .com domain and I own .net. he has posted an iframe on the site linking to mine, and at the top of if he has posted that "This site is for sale" and I need to stop this happening. is it possible to use PHP or javascript to stop that particular site from either accessing my site, or redirecting his iframe to somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Thats easy:
Say he use your file this way

a.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="sample.html"/>
</html>
```

just add the following lines to your already existing on Document load function:

```
window.onload = function(e) {
    if ( window.self !== window.top ) {
    //Your site is in i frame
    //just redirect to his own site if you feel like there will be an endless recursion so nothing will load probably.
    //You can put your custom action if this is not what you want
        window.self.location = "a.html"
    //would be pretty good enough :D
    }
};
```